# If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $|f_n| \leq g$, then $|f| \leq g$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $g$ and $f_n$ are defined on $(0,\infty)$, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every compact subset of $(0,\infty)$, and $|f_n| \leq g$.  I want to prove that $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$.

This seems so obviously true because $f_n$ can get as close to $f$ as you want but I don't know how to formally show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, suppose for a contradiction that there exists $x\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)>g(x)$. Let $\epsilon=f(x)-g(x)>0$. Then, use uniform convergence to get the contradiction that $f_{n}(x)>g(x)$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Let $\epsilon = |f(x)|-g(x)>0$.  By uniform convergence $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < |f(x)|-g(x)$ for n large.  From there?

Comment: You can choose $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_{N}(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. On the other hand, $|f(x)-f_{N}(x)|\geq |f(x)|-|f_{N}(x)|\geq|f(x)|-g(x)\geq f(x)-g(x)>\epsilon$.

Comment: I think your second inequality uses $|f_N(x)| \geq g(x)$ which isn't what we're assuming.

Comment: No, it uses exactly what we are assuming. Namely, $|f_{N}(x)|\leq g(x)$ by assumption so it follows that $|f(x)|-|f_{N}(x)|\geq |f(x)|-g(x)$ (the right side is smaller because we are subtracting a bigger non-negative number from the same non-negative $|f(x)|$)

Answer (score 1):

Take $a\in(0,+\infty)$. Then $\{a\}$ is compact, and therefore $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$ there, which simply means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(a)=f(a)$. And therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|f_n(a)\bigr|=\bigl|f(a)\bigr|$. So, since each $\bigl|f_n(a)\bigr|$ is smaller than or equal to $g(a)$, $\bigl|f(a)\bigr|\leqslant g(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is that they converge pointwise, and that $\{x: |x| \le y\}$ is a closed set for all $y$.

Comment: Can you elaborate or show a first step at least?  I'm not following.

Comment: See [lower semi-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity). The absolute value $|\cdot | \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is lower semi continuous (since the sublevel sets $\{ x \colon |x| \leq y\}$ are closed. Hence, if $\lim f_n(x) = f(x)\ $ then $ \ f(x)=| \liminf f_n(x) | \leq \liminf |f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$.